# Getting nodes neighbors with the CGAL python binding

Tags: python, binding, cgal, triangulation, delaunay

I'm trying to make a dictionary from my 2D Delaunay triangulation similar to : **{node_index : [list of nodes neighbors]}**. I'm using the cgal python binding to compute the Delaunay triangulation on a set of 2D point cloud.

Unfortunately I didn't find enough documentation in python on how to get each node's neighbors from the triangulation.

I would be very grateful if you could help me solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following:

```
from CGAL.CGAL_Kernel import Point_2
from CGAL.CGAL_Triangulation_2 import Delaunay_triangulation_2
from CGAL.CGAL_Triangulation_2 import Delaunay_triangulation_2_Vertex_circulator

t = Delaunay_triangulation_2()


v1 = t.insert(Point_2(1, 2))
t.insert(Point_2(3, 2))
t.insert(Point_2(3, 44))
t.insert(Point_2(34, 4))
t.insert(Point_2(11, 45))
t.insert(Point_2(11, 7))

print("Nb vertices ", t.number_of_vertices())

circulator = t.incident_vertices(v1)
done = circulator.next()

while(1):
  v = circulator.next()
  print(v.point())
  if v == done:
    break
```

`incident_vertices()` returns a circulator, i.e. an iterator that loops infinitely.